# How to display a list of videos in ionic 3

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

How do i display a list of videos from my server using ionic. The video tag doesnt seem to work on ionic. When used, the videos dont seem to show up.
This is how am using the video tag:

```
<video>
   <source="theurlofthevideo.mp4" type="type/mp4">
</video>
```

What seems to be the issue. Doesnt work in the browser and on android as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it as shown below.

**Note:** This is just a sample.Convert it to your use case.

```
<ion-content overflow-scroll="true">
  <video controls="controls" preload="metadata" autoplay="autoplay" webkit-playsinline="webkit-playsinline" class="videoPlayer">
   <source src="./assets/videos/Part_1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
</ion-content>
```

Working sample: [**codepen**](https://codepen.io/perrygovier/pen/cazjd)

**And** also I would like to recommend to use [**native video Player plugin**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/video-player/) for that.

> A Cordova plugin that simply allows you to immediately play a video in
>   fullscreen mode.

```
ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/moust/cordova-plugin-videoplayer.git 
npm install --save @ionic-native/video-player
```

Comment: What are te benefits on that plugin vs html5 video tag ? I need to work on something similar. Thanks !

Comment: it is only for android what about ios platform

Comment: You can use `Videogular` https://videogular.github.io/videogular2/ @KhurshidAnsari

Comment: Thanks for but some other issue. may be version. i m using ionic 3

Comment: You can use `6.1.1` https://github.com/videogular/videogular2/releases/tag/v6.1.1 @KhurshidAnsari

Comment: Thanks but it is not working. I am doing in different way.

Comment: You need to put your issues on a different question. I have implemented it and all are working fine on both platforms. @KhurshidAnsari